# UPDATE THE EVENTS ARE NOT WORKING....

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, textarea

UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE

thank you :))) I did What u told me

I put  frame.add(FirstScreen) first

they appeared .....

but now the events are not working , why???????

Can u help me again???

I'm sorry ........

..................

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class InterFace extends JFrame implements ActionListener,ItemListener
{

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Al-murshed Dictionary");
JPanel FirstScreen = new JPanel();
JPanel SecondScreen = new JPanel();
JPanel ThirdScreen = new JPanel();
JPanel ForthScreen = new JPanel();
JButton Translate = new JButton ("Translate");
JButton About = new JButton ("About");
JButton Help= new JButton ("Help");
JButton Quit= new JButton ("Quit");
JButton Quit1= new JButton ("Quit");
JButton Quit2= new JButton ("Quit");
JButton Back= new JButton ("Back");
JButton Back1= new JButton ("Back");
JTextField WordField = new JTextField("Write Your Word Here",50);
JTextArea ArbField = new JTextArea(40,40);
JTextArea EngField = new JTextArea(40,40);
CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout ();

public  InterFace()
{

 FirstScreen.setLayout(c1);

 SecondScreen.add(WordField);
 SecondScreen.add(Translate);
 ThirdScreen.add(Back);
 ForthScreen.add(Back1);
 ThirdScreen.add(Quit1);
 ForthScreen.add(Quit2);

 FirstScreen.add(SecondScreen,"1");
 FirstScreen.add(ThirdScreen,"2");
 FirstScreen.add(ForthScreen,"3");

 JPanel controlButtons = new JPanel();
 controlButtons.add(Help);
 controlButtons.add(About);
 controlButtons.add(Quit);

 JPanel wordTranslate = new JPanel();
 wordTranslate.add(WordField);
 wordTranslate.add(Translate);

 JPanel controlTextArea = new JPanel();
 controlTextArea.add(EngField);
 controlTextArea.add(ArbField);

 c1.show(FirstScreen,"1");

About.addActionListener(this);
Back.addActionListener(this);
Help.addActionListener(this);
Back1.addActionListener(this);
Quit.addActionListener(this);
Quit1.addActionListener(this);
Quit2.addActionListener(this);

frame.add(FirstScreen);
Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
pane.add(wordTranslate, BorderLayout.NORTH);
pane.add(controlTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
pane.add(controlButtons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

//EventHandler
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

 if(e.getSource()==About)
 c1.show(FirstScreen,"2");

 if(e.getSource()==Help)
 c1.show(FirstScreen,"3");

 if(e.getSource()==Quit)
 System.exit(0);

 if(e.getSource()==Quit1)
 System.exit(0);

if(e.getSource()==Quit2)
    System.exit(0);

 if(e.getSource()==Back)
 c1.show(FirstScreen,"1");

 if(e.getSource()==Back1)
 c1.show(FirstScreen,"1");

 }
 public static void main (String args[])
{
 InterFace d = new InterFace ();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pane.add(controlTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
...
frame.add(FirstScreen);
```

First you add the text area panel to the content pane.

Then you add the "FirstScreen" to the frame.

The problem is that when you add the "FirstScreen" to the frame you are really adding it to the content pane of the frame. So basically you are replacing the text area panel with the first screen.

Also, follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Thank you :))

I did this now but the events are not working anymore (about/help)

    JPanel wordTranslate = new JPanel();
    wordTranslate.add(WordField);
    wordTranslate.add(Translate);

    frame.add(FirstScreen);
  Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
  pane.add(wordTranslate, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  pane.add(controlTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  pane.add(controlButtons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);